AHA Guidelines on dyslipidemia 2018
If I understood correctly the AHA guidelines 2018 on dyslipidemia say that regardless of age person who has LDL 190 should take statin.
If we take a person A in middle thirties and person say B in middle fifties and they both show LDL 190, isn't it the case that there was much more time for person B to have spent with higher levels of LDL than person A? How come they are put "in the same basket"?
Some of my questions are

Can't person A do some tests to actually assess the atherosclerosis (if present) and use that information in treatment planning?
How tight is the threshold, what if person has 180 instead of 190?


Why would you treat the two patients differently? No matter how long they've had dyslipidemia, the elevated LDL is going to cause harm in both patients if untreated.

@Gmed I understand what OP is saying, but I don't see how it would change the treatment for either patient.

@Gmed The guidelines say otherwise. Obviously, every patient is different and doctors are going to use their judgement, but preventing atherosclerosis is better than waiting for it to develop.
